# В 1,8 раз или раза? В 5,5 раз или раза?

Tags: числительные

Добрый день, как правильно написать: в 1,8 раз или раза, в 5,5 раз или раза?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно:

в 1,8 раза (в одну целую и восемь десятых раза);

в 5,5 раза (в пять целых и пять десятых раза).

Часто используется и такой вариант:

в 5,5 раз. Читается как "в пять с половиной раз..."

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

**Правильно:**  в 1,8 (одну целую, **восемь десятых**) **раза**, в 5,5 (пять целых, **пять десятых**) **раза**.  **В восемь десятых раза**, **в пять десятых раза** ***(согласование в родительном падеже)***.

Comment: Это не согласование, а управление: пять (чего? )десятых частей (чего? )раза

Comment: Понял. Спасибо, Людмила!